# Iterate MongoDB collection to pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I'm trying to display a MongoDB collection of employees into Pug. I know it has something to do with the first 'data' object. I cannot figure out how to render the data within the array.

**MongoDB collection:**

```
{  
"data":[  
  {  
     "active":true,
     "userName":"example",
     "employeeDetails":{  
        "personalDetails":{  
           "firstName":"Dennis",
           "lastName":"Glover",
           "emailAddress":"example@example.com"
        }
     }
  },
  {
     "active": false,
     "userName": example2,
     "employeeDetails": {
        "personalDetails": {
           "firstName": "Ben",
           "lastName": "Dover",
           "emailAddress": "example2@example.com"
        }
     }
  },
]
}
```

**Express:**

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the Server', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);

        var employeecollection = db.collection('employees');

        // Find all employees
        employeecollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, employeeResult) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else if (employeeResult.length) {
                res.render('employeelist', {
                    'employeelist': employeeResult,
                });
            } else {
                res.send('No documents found');
            }
            db.close();
        });
    };

});
```

**Pug:**

```
table
each employee in employeelist
    tr#employee_list_item    
      td #{employee.userName}
```

I have fiddled around got it working with Angular2 using ng-repeat, however I cannot seem to get it to render in Pug unless I strip out the 'data' object in the array (which needs to be there).

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `console.log(employeeResult)`?

Comment: Sure, I get the following:

[ { _id: 5892b3ae79fb9d023308dce7,
    data:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ] } ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I can see `employeelist[0].data` is the array you want to iterate on.

Change `employeelist` to `employeelist[0].data`

```
table 
each employee in employeelist[0].data
    tr#employee_list_item
        td #{employee.userName}
```

Update. Alternative method:

As Mohit suggested, if you send from the route itself, then your original code will work.

```
    // Find all employees
    employeecollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, employeeResult) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else if (employeeResult.length) {
            res.render('employeelist', {
                'employeelist': employeeResult[0].data,
            });
        } else {
            res.send('No documents found');
        }
        db.close();
    });
```

Then, in your view:
**Pug**

```
table
each employee in employeelist
    tr#employee_list_item    
      td #{employee.userName}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you! - However I get the following error displayed in my browser from Mongoose:

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: perhaps it should be employeelist[0].data? This can be modified in the route file itself to send the data in required format.

Comment: Yes it should be `employeelist[0].data`. I will update my answer. And, yes, if data is sent in the required format from the route itself, then original code of OP will work.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it!

Comment: Hair I could help you out. Please upvote my answer if it worked for you.